# Time Capsule stuck on makingbackup disk available

Tags: time-capsule

I am an IT person, and i have set up two Time capsule and the backup is not working. It just stays stuck. I can use the TC as a file server, no problem. I have tried everything, fixing the backups, erasing the disk, creating the backups again, checking updates...

This ahappened on two separate locations. Same problems.

I can provide with some console but there is not much going on.

Many thanks

Comment: Without more details it could definitively be anything. Can you add relevant entries both from the Mac and the TC logs?

Comment: I finally got it sorted. I changed to shorter names for computers and TC. I left in despair and it worked after 48 hours.... I love Apple but i will not recommend TC for backup anymore on Wifi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by changing the mac names and TC abem to shorter names.. After 48 H it worked

Answer (score 0):

It had happened to me in the past and I fixed it by rebooting the Time Capsule.